# how to make my python executable file work properly?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I code a simple email bot to send automaticlly an email. After that I try to create an exe file with pyinstaller on cmd. Now I have a lot of files and my exe doent work. I try to run it from python's idle and works every time without any errors. What should I do?

that's my code:

```
import os
from datetime import date
import schedule
import time
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage


        def mail():
        if date.today().day == 9:
        EMAIL_ADRESS = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
        EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS') 

        msg = EmailMessage()
        msg['Subject'] = 'test'  
        msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADRESS
        msg['To'] = 'someones adress' 
        msg.set_content('1st test')          


        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
            smtp.login(EMAIL_ADRESS,EMAIL_PASSWORD)
            smtp.send_message(msg)
        return


        schedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(mail)

        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Well...... What's the error? Please also reformat your posting as the indent is broken

Comment: @frlan the py file has no errors. for some reason the exe file of this code doesn't working. if you can help i will appreciate

Comment: Without seeing any error it's hard to help.